# RabbitMQ (PHP) Is it possible to check if there is listener to a channel before posting?

Tags: php, rabbitmq, php-amqplib

using php-amqplib, is it possible to check if there is a listener to a channel before sending a message. The idea behind it is only to publish a message when there is some audience only.

I looked at the code and was not able to find something explaining it.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying to do this kinda defeats messaging "fire and forget" idea, but you can issue a `queue_declare` with `passive=true` to get the number of messages and consumers in a queue.

On the other hand, why not make your consumers declare their own exclusive auto-delete queues, so if the consumer goes away, then the message will be automatically discarded by RabbitMQ

Comment: I like the idea of auto-delete queues but I lack the knowledge. Do you have a link to an example/howto ?

Comment: I need to read it indeed. I hope I'll find what I'm looking for. Thank you :)